# PHP - Looping inside a loop, maybe?

Tags: php

I am currently using a foreach loop to display some radio buttons like so

```
<?php
foreach($roles as $role){
    $output .= '<div class="row">';
    $output .= '    <input name="_'.$role->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$role->key.'" class="radio" />';
    $output .= '    <label for="'.$role->key.'" style="text-transform: lowercase;">'.$role->name.'</label>';
    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

?>

So thats fairly straight forward .... The bit that i need to do next is confusing ... i need to take the $role->key and see if it matches an entry in another table, if so, echo 'checked="checked"' on the radio button.

It will need to be matched by the $role->key and also the $userid.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can write a function with a boolean return that Queries to see if the $userid and $role->key exists in the table.  if it does return true else return false.  Lets say the

function is checkExist it would go something like this.

```
    $output .= '    <input name="_'.$role->key.'" type="radio" id="'.$role->key.'" class="radio"';
    if(checkExist($userid, $role->key))
         $output .= ' checked '; 
    $output .= '/>';

function checkExist($userid, $key){
     //do a query to check if userid $key exists in table
     //code will look like this :-
     //$search = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE user='$userid' and   key='$key'");
     //$total_records = mysql_num_rows($search);
     //the mysql_num_rows() will return the number of records from the query...

     if(mysql_num_rows() == 0)
         return false;
     else
         return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ... Is there any way you could give me an example of the checkExist() code? ... Im kind of new to doing things in functions

Comment: do you want to query that many times?  if size doesn't prohibit maybe the whole table should be loaded and checked against. i guess its an issue of $roles size vs tables

Answer (score 0):

You can put loops wherever you want, even inside of another one.

Comment: When i put the loop inside the one i already have, it echos out the result the amount of times the first loop results.

Comment: is the $userid in a MySQL table? or another php array?

Comment: The user id is global $userid when the page loads ... in the table with the keys, it also has the userid .. so what it needs to do is link the current userid to the one in the database, take the key assocciated and print echo 'checked="checked"' to the ones it finds in the table

Answer (score 0):

for checkExists($id) you can write something like:

```
function checkExists($id){
    $result = $mysql_query("SELECT ID from tablename WHERE ID=$id");
    return mysql_num_rows($result);
}
```

btw. I'm writing directly here, you might need to tune up something